# Having trouble with virtual functions(C++)

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

So I made this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Enemy{
public:
    virtual void attack(){}
    int attackPower;
        void setAttackPower(int a)
        {
            attackPower = a;
        }
};

class Ninja: public Enemy{
public:
    void attack(){
        cout<<"ninja  "<< attackPower<<endl;
    }
};

class Monster: public Enemy{

    public:
    void attack(){
        cout<<"monster  "<< attackPower<<endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Ninja n;
    Monster m;
    Enemy *enemy1= &n;
    Enemy *enemy2 = &m;
    enemy1->attack();
    enemy2->attack();
    enemy1->setAttackPower(29);
    enemy2->setAttackPower(99);

    return 0;
}
```

And the problem I'm having is that when I print out the attack power for like enemy1 it's not what I set it to, 29, its some huge number.  So what I'm wondering is why is that number huge number occurring and how can I fix it?

Comment: You are attacking before setting the attack power.

Comment: Try this and crack this. The simplest code to show the same behavior would be:: int main( void ) { int a ; std::cout<<a ; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise attackpower first by

`enemy1->setAttackPower(29);
 enemy2->setAttackPower(99);`

Then print them,

`enemy1->attack();
 enemy2->attack();`

The `main` would be like

```
int main()
{
    Ninja n;
    Monster m;
    Enemy *enemy1= &n;
    Enemy *enemy2 = &m;

    enemy1->setAttackPower(29); // set the attack power first
    enemy2->setAttackPower(99);
     enemy1->attack();          // then print it otherwise junk values will be printed
    enemy2->attack();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You called `attack()` before `setAttackPower()`.  Because you did not initialize either `m` or `n`, they have garbage values.

Answer (score -1):

It's been a quite a while since I wrote any C++ but does this code:

```
void attack(){
    cout<<"monster  "<< attackPower<<endl;
}
```

also need to the *virtual* keyword:

```
virtual void attack(){
    cout<<"monster  "<< attackPower<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Its not mandatory but its always good to add the keyword. In any case the overridden function is considered as "virtual" in the derived class. Also, in C++11 you can write "void attack() override {}" to explicitly declare that you're overriding a virtual method.

Comment: I no it's not mandatory but without the *virtual* keyword I don't think it's going to work? By not having *virtual* doesn't that mean the function gets called directly (i.e. it is **not called** via a vtable lookup). In which case how could the call from the pointer to the base class (which **is using** the vtable lookup) ever manage to call that non vtable function found in the derived class. I also would have though the compiler would generate a warning for this, but as I said it has been a while and C++ compilers have changed since I did any C++ coding.

Comment: Abhineet, I had the exact same idea. I ran the code in a online compiler and it worked. So I have learnt something today. Thanks for pointing this out.